# To UNION or Not to UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2012

I am currently running into an issue with my UNION clause. I am trying to figure out how many orders I am import via each day. The problem is, I have two tables that these orders are stored in OLDORDERHEADER and ORDERHEADER. After an order is completed, it moves from the ORDERHEADER table into the OLD. Both have the same exact columns, so I figured I would use a UNION clause and be fine. Well once I run my query, it prints two rows, identical dates and different qtys'. Which is to be expected, I just want to combine them into one row and a sum of the qty's for each hour.
Here is what I am working with:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(8),recvtime,1) AS 'Day', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '12AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '3AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '4AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '5AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '6AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '7AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '8AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '9AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '10AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '11AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '12PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 13 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 14 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '3PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 16 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '4PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 17 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '5PM',
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '6PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 19 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '7PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '8PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 21 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '9PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 22 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '10PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 23 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '11PM'

FROM MCK_HVS.OLDORDERHEADER WITH(NOLOCK)

WHERE CAST(recvtime as DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)

GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(8),recvtime,1)

UNION

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(8),recvtime,1) AS 'Day', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '12AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '3AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '4AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '5AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '6AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '7AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '8AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '9AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '10AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '11AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '12PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 13 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 14 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '3PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 16 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '4PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 17 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '5PM',
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '6PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 19 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '7PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '8PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 21 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '9PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 22 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '10PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 23 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '11PM'

FROM MCK_HVS.ORDERHEADER WITH(NOLOCK)

WHERE CAST(recvtime as DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)

GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(8),recvtime,1)

ORDER BY CONVERT(varchar(8),recvtime,1)desc
```

Comment: So make that query a Common table expression and then write your sum's by hour and group by day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might also consider `PIVOT` for a more concise syntax.

I find the use of `UNION` dubious and am assuming that you actually need `UNION ALL` too.

```
WITH CombinedOrderHeader
     AS (SELECT recvtime
         FROM   ORDERHEADER
         UNION ALL
         SELECT recvtime
         FROM   oldORDERHEADER),
     PvtSource(htt, Day)
     AS (SELECT FORMAT(recvtime, 'htt'),
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), recvtime, 1)
         FROM   CombinedOrderHeader
         WHERE  recvtime >= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
                AND recvtime < DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)))
SELECT *
FROM   PvtSource PIVOT (COUNT(htt) FOR htt IN ([12AM], [1AM], [2AM], [3AM], [4AM], [5AM], 
                                               [6AM], [7AM], [8AM], [9AM], [10AM], [11AM], 
                                               [12PM], [1PM], [2PM], [3PM], [4PM], [5PM], 
                                               [6PM], [7PM], [8PM], [9PM], [10PM], [11PM] 
                                             )) P
```

Comment: The Pivot allowed my query to run a lot faster I will definitely take that. I have a long night of researching these methods!

Comment: @AlanWillever it will probably be the `UNION ALL’ that is responsible for any performance benefit as it isn't spending time looking for and removing duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

No need to write the entire query twice, you can use the union as a derived table (or a cte) and do the group by and sum only once:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT recvtime
    FROM MCK_HVS.OLDORDERHEADER WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE CAST(recvtime as DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)

    UNION 

    SELECT recvtime
    FROM MCK_HVS.ORDERHEADER WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE CAST(recvtime as DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)
)    

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(8),recvtime,1) AS 'Day', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '12AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '3AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '4AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '5AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '6AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '7AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '8AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '9AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '10AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '11AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '12PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 13 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 14 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '3PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 16 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '4PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 17 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '5PM',
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '6PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 19 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '7PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '8PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 21 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '9PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 22 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '10PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 23 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '11PM'

FROM CTE 
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(8),recvtime,1)
ORDER BY CONVERT(varchar(8),recvtime,1) DESC
```

Comment: That worked perfectly,  I did not know you could lead a query with (with). I will definitely have to research that some more. Thanks again everyone. I appreciate it

Comment: @AlanWillever `UNION` will remove duplicates before doing the `GROUP BY` is that what you need?

Comment: @MartinSmith I think a union is the better choice in this case since union all might return records that are true duplicates and I don't think the OP wants this. I was actually thinking to write something about that in my answer but then I came to this conclusion. However, it's good that you pointed that out since I didn't.

Comment: @AlanWillever - welcome to StackOverFlow - you should upvvote any answers that helped you - and mark the best answer as 'accepted'.

Comment: @AlanWillever [Glad to help :-)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291325/how-to-show-appreciation-to-a-user-on-stackoverflow/291327#291327)

Comment: @StanShaw Actually, you can only upvote once you have 15 reputation points - Alan has only 6 for now...

Comment: @ZoharPeled Ahhh - you learn something every day!  At least I wasn't vote-begging for myself!

Comment: Well hopefully duplicate orders across tables will be identifiable by something other than timestamp such as orderid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT
    DAY,
    SUM(12AM) AS [12AM]
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
FROM (
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(8),recvtime,1) AS 'Day', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '12AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '3AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '4AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '5AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '6AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '7AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '8AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '9AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '10AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '11AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '12PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 13 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 14 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '3PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 16 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '4PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 17 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '5PM',
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '6PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 19 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '7PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '8PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 21 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '9PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 22 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '10PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 23 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '11PM'

FROM MCK_HVS.OLDORDERHEADER WITH(NOLOCK)

WHERE CAST(recvtime as DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)

GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(8),recvtime,1)

UNION

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(8),recvtime,1) AS 'Day', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '12AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '3AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '4AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '5AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '6AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '7AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '8AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '9AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '10AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '11AM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '12PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 13 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 14 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 15 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '3PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 16 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '4PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 17 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '5PM',
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 18 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '6PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 19 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '7PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 20 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '8PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 21 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '9PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 22 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '10PM', 
SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(hour,recvtime) = 23 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '11PM'

FROM MCK_HVS.ORDERHEADER WITH(NOLOCK)

WHERE CAST(recvtime as DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)

GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(8),recvtime,1)) AS [SOURCE]

ORDER BY 1 desc
```

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/defd2/9

```
 SELECT COUNT(ID), CASE WHEN HOUR < 12 THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),HOUR) + 'AM' 
                ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),HOUR-12) + 'PM' END 
   FROM (
          SELECT id, DATEPART(hour,recvtime) AS HOUR FROM ORDERHEADER 
              UNION 
          SELECT id, DATEPART(hour,recvtime) AS HOUR FROM oldORDERHEADER ) A
     GROUP BY A.HOUR
```

Comment: This will not include an hour if there were no orders placed with Count = 0.

Comment: @mr_eclair, the query I have proposed is executed in two steps, first, the UNION which will concatenate all the results from both tables and I don't infer with id directly, the second part is the GROUP BY, which will count the numbers of orders by ID. You are right, it will not generate a record for a missing time. This could be done linking this query with a UDF that generates records for empty hours.